# Magento 2: Custom controller page showing in inspect element but not on browser

Tags: magento2, phtml

I am calling a custom phtml through a controller which is triggered by an ajax call on button click. When I click the button the page is showing in inspect element preview but not redirecting o browser.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

My controller:

```
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action   
{   
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
  
    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)   
    {   
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;   
        parent::__construct($context);   
    }   
 
    public function execute()   
    {
        
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $registry = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class);

        $this->resultJsonFactory = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory::class);
        // $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        $categoryName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('catname'); 
        // $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();   
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $session = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session::class);

     $test = $session->setCatname($categoryName);

    //  echo $session->getCatname(); 
    $this->resultFactory = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::class);

    $page = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

/** @var Template $block */
$block = $page->getLayout()->getBlock('serviceprovider');
$block->setData('custom_parameter', $categoryName);

// if ($session->getCatname()) {
//     $result = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock("Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vshops\ListBlock")->setTemplate("Magemechanic_ServiceProvider::list.phtml")->toHtml();

//     $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
//         ->createBlock('Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vshops\ListBlock')
//         ->setTemplate('Magemechanic_ServiceProvider::list.phtml')
//         ->toHtml();
        
//         $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
//         return $result;
// } else {

    return $page;

// }


     

    //   $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock("Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vshops\ListBlock")->setKey('dfd')->setTemplate("Magemechanic_ServiceProvider::list.phtml")->toHtml();

     
        // if (!empty($categoryName)) {
        //     $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
        //     ->createBlock('Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vshops\ListBlock')
        //     ->setTemplate('Magemechanic_ServiceProvider::list.phtml')
        //     ->toHtml();
            
        //     $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
        //     return $result;
        // } else {
            // return $resultPage;   

        // }



        // echo $categoryName;
        // exit;
        // $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        // $registry = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class);

        // $params = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data'); 
        // $registry->register('categoryName', $params);

    }   
}
```

Ajax:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxUrl,
                data: {catname:catName},
                cache: false,
                showLoader: true,

                // beforeSend: function () {
                //     $('body').trigger('processStart');
                // },
                success: function (res) {
                    $('body').trigger('processStop');
                    // window.location.href = ajaxUrl;

                }

            });
```

Comment: Hi there , in the JS file ,please check what are you doing after the page elements are returned in the sucess function or complete function of the Jquery Ajax object , my suggestion would be you can use the JS functions to update the whole DOM elements after the page is returned from the request as a response.Thanks.

Comment: How can I do that? I have updated the question with the ajax code.

Comment: Again hi , after the page has been returned in the success function , you can use like this - $("body").html("new content"); , and you can add other events like triggering a change to let know the users and this is optional from my side , if you need it , please use it. please let me know if it works - Thanks.

Comment: I tried this but I want to pass the data on page reload because $("body").html("new content") does not run js etc